# Wrapping of selected string

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'd like to create hot key for wrapping of selected line. Ideally it should work like in this example:

1. Selection of string: ":include => [:profile => :user]"
2. Pressing of F6 key
3. Selected string should be modified to "lambda {{ :include => [:profile => [:user]] }}"

I've implemented following solution:

```
 nmap <F6> :%s/<C-r>+/lambda {{ <C-r>+ }}/gc
```

but it doesn't work, because selected line contains not escaped element "]" and "%s" cannot find line because of this. I use vim-gnome.
What solutions can you advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution is

```
xnoremap <F6> slambda{{ <c-r>" }}<esc>
```

There is also the old way (the one that doesn't change the *unnamed register*, but which is also incompatible with `redo`)

```
xnoremap <F6> <esc>`>a}}<esc>`<ilambda {{<esc>
```

Then, are are also plugins. With my [lh-brackets](https://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhBrackets#The_bracketing_subsystem), it would be defined with

```
Brackets! lambda\ {{ }} -trigger=<F6> -insert=0
```

(indeed there is more to type, but it can also generates mappings for normal and insert modes)

Comment: Note regarding the 2nd solution: Appending (`'>a`) must be done before inserting (`'<i`), otherwise the |marks| used the end-of-selection will be messed up during the insertion.

Answer (score 3):

The [surround.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) is a widely used plugin for surrounding text. It can be customized (but doesn't support function keys, only "normal" letters):

```
:let g:surround_108 = "lambda {{ \r }}"
```

With this, you can surround the selected text with `sl` (`108` is the code for lowercase `l`), also from normal mode via `ys{motion}l`.

Comment: A slightly more maintainable way is `let g:surround_{char2nr('l')} = "lambda {{ \r }}"`. You can also set buffer local variables in case you want this to only apply to certain filetypes. e.g `let b:surround_108 = "lambda {{ \r }}"` and add to ~/after/ftplugins/foo.vim` where `foo` is your filetype. See `:h surround-customizing` for more information.